# Filter eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, doctrine

Im using laravel for a project i am wanting to create an endpoint which filters and searches a `Film` model and returns a collection of films that match the chosen filter options which will be `Options, Location and Age Rating` picked by the user.

I have created a query with how i would initially join the tables in symfony(hopefully its correct) but im unsure on how i adjust this to be more Laravel or eloquent.

**Film Model**

```
    public function location(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }

    public function options(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Option::class,
            'film_options',
            'film_id',
            'option_id'
        );
    }

 public function ageRatings(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            AgeRating::class,
            'film_age_ratings',
            'film_id',
            'age_rating_id'
        );
    }
```

**Query in Doctrine**

```
Select *
        From films  f
        Join film_options fo on f.id = fo.film_id
        Join options o on o.id = fo.option_id 
        Join film_age_ratings fa on f.id = fa.film_id
        Join age_ratings a on a.id = fa.age_rating_id
        Join location l on l.id = p.location_id
```

How would i write this query within laravel?

Comment: Please can you show what inputs/attributes you're going to be submitting as filters and which tables/fields those filters relate to

Comment: So' categorie's table will be a filter, it contains 2 columns one 'main' with a list of seeded data and a 'sub' column with seeded data then when a user inputs an option from both columns it returns a film with those categories.' Age rating' table has one column with seeded numbers called 'age' when a user selects a number it returns all films with that number, location table has 2 columns 'country' and 'city' with seeded data for both you select a country and city and it returns films based upon the users input

Comment: Ok from that I've got the filters are **categories**: `main` and `sub` **age_ratings**: `number`, **locations**: `city` and `country`. Is this correct? In fact, please may you add the html for the form to your question.

Comment: @rwd i have added a filters section in my question, i am doing this within an API the front end is going to be within JS which ill be working on after, its just an endpoint that filters data on the backend for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you're after you can use a mixture of [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#conditional-clauses) and [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$films = Film
    ::when($request->input('first'), function ($query, $first) {
        $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($first) {
            $query->where('first', $first);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('second'), function ($query, $second) {
        $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($second) {
            $query->where('second', $second);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('age'), function ($query, $age) {
        $query->whereHas('ageRatings', function ($query) use ($age) {
            $query->where('age', $age);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('country'), function ($query, $country) {
        $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($country) {
            $query->where('country', $country);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('city'), function ($query, $city) {
        $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($city) {
            $query->where('city', $city);
        });
    })
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Essentially, what the above is doing is saying when you have a non-empty value submitted it will add a where clause to the query for that relationship
 e.g. is `main` is submitted it will limit the films to only ones that have categories when main is the submitted value.

---

Also, just an FYI, you don't need to add the `from(...)` method when using Eloquent.

---

A simple way to limit the number of lines would be to add [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes) to your `Film` model e.g.

In your `Film` model:

```
public function scopeHasMain($query, $main)
{
    $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use($first) {
        $query->where('first', $first);
    });
}
```

Then your `when()` method would be:

```
when($request->input('first'), function ($query, $first) {
    $query->hasFirst($first);
})
```

Comment: @lilnoobcoder Yes, it would filter based on what the user submits, if the value is empty then it will ignore it. This would just go straight in your controller.

Comment: @lilnoobcoder There a a few different things you could do to reduce the code. You could create different scopes for the attributes (I'll add an example to my answer) or potentially look at using a package specifically for filtering e.g. https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable or https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-query-builder/v2/features/filtering/

Comment: also is there a way to extract the code without using packages?

Comment: @lilnoobcoder The first param pasted to `when()` will be passed as the second param for the closure. Yeah, in theory, there are plenty of ways you could refactor this. If you have a Laracast's account I would suggest watching this video: https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-techniques/episodes/4, however, the first package I recommended will essentially give you what's in the episode with a bit more functionality.

Comment: thankyou very much for the help and solutions, i understand how it all works now, should help me if i ever want to do some form of filtering again in the future :) have a good day!

Comment: @lilnoobcoder You should only need to change the `->input('sub')` to `->input('subcategory')`.

Comment: @lilnoobcoder No, it won't matter at all. You get the value from the request using `$request->input('name-of-input')`, this value is then passed to the closure (2nd param) and then the 1st of `->where()` is the name of the db field.

Comment: @lilnoobcoder No, you would need to use something like `whereIn()` instead of `where()` and the input would be an array instead of a string.

Comment: @lilnoobcoder I would suggest creating a new question as its starting to go outside of the scope of this one. One of the points of Stack overflow is to help other people who might be experiencing the same (or similar) issues. If questions and answers keep getting updated/changed then it kind of goes against that idea.

Comment: @lilnoobcoder I would do but it looks like you deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereHas` method as shown in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Example:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

//...

$optionIds = [/* Option ids to filter by */];
$films = Film::whereHas('options', function (Builder $query) use ($optionIds) {
    $query->whereIn('options.id', $optionIds);
})->get();
```

Comment: what if i am going to be filtering on category columns so in the migration 'main' and 'sub' which are columns which have seeded data such as arts for main and drawing for sub how would i join that table and filter it?

Comment: You mean you would like to check multiple columns in the categories table?

Comment: the results change depending on the users input

Comment: I see, but are both those columns in the categories table? can you update your question to add this usecase.

Comment: Yes they're i have updated the question with a filters section to show the different columns