# Get all models that have a specific relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application I am building a filter function. You can filter model A by selecting what kind of relations it should have with model B. Model A has a many-to-many relation with Model B.
So for example, model A1 has a relation with model B1, B2, B3, model A2 has a relation with B2, B3 and model A3 has a relation with model B3.

If you select only B3 in the filter model A1, A2 and A3 should show. If you select B3 and B2 only A1 and A2 should show.

Is there a way I could solve this issue and how? I have no idea if my example is clear, if not, please tell me.

I tried `whereHas` by doing the following:

```
$gyms = Gym::whereHas('facilities', function (Builder $query) use ($facilities) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $facilities);
})->get();
```

The problem is that if I want all gyms with facility 1 and facility 2 it shows gyms with only facility 1 or facility 2 but I need models that have both.

Gym is model A from my example and Facility is model B. `$facilities` is an array of Facility ID's.

Comment: Did you try using [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Filter query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695291/laravel-filter-query)

Comment: I have updated my question with whereHas but it doesn't give any results.

Comment: @Rwd in this case the relation isn't many-to-many.

Comment: As long as it isn't a `morph` relationship it won't matter.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `$facilities` is an array of `id`s?

Comment: @Rwd yes, it is.

Comment: I'm confused, in your question is says **Model A** has a `many-to-many` relationship with **Model B** but in the comments you've said it **isn't** a `many-to-many` relationship?? What is the relationship between `Gym` and `Facility`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a "where in" clause in Laravel the method is [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses).

```
$gyms = Gym::whereHas('facilities', function (Builder $query) use ($facilities) {
    $query->whereIn('facilities.id', $facilities);
})->get();
```

The above will return results that match one or more of the`id`s in the array. If you want to only return matches that contain all of the ids in the array you can specify this with the 3rd and 4th params of `whereHas()`:

```
$gyms = Gym::whereHas('facilities', function (Builder $query) use ($facilities) {
    $query->whereIn('facilities.id', $facilities);
}, '=', count($facilities)) //<-- This bit
    ->get();
```

The above assumes there aren't any duplicate `id`'s in `$facilities` and that all the `id`'s exist in the database.

Comment: whoops, my bad. But still this show all the results that have facility 1 or facility 2. I only need the results that have facility 1 and facility 2.

Comment: Sorry, had some other things to do. Tried this and works exactly like I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

WhereIn() evaluates to true if the column match one of the array. If you need AND logic (not OR logic), use normal where()

```
$gyms = Gym::query()
foreach ($facilities as $key => $value) {
    $gyms->whereHas('facilities', function (Builder $query) use ($facilities) {
        $query->where('facilities.id', $value);
    });
}
$gyms = $gyms->get();
```

Comment: This will not work as your basically saying: "where id = 1 AND id = 2 AND id = 3 ...".

Comment: ...get me the rows where the `id` equals **1** but also where that same row's `id` also equals **2** and **3**.